# plm() versus lm() with multiple fixed effects

Tags: r, lm, plm

I am attempting to run a model with county, year, and state:year fixed effects. The lm() approach looks like this:

`lm <- lm(data = mydata, formula = y ~ x + county + year + state:year`

where county, year, and state:year are all factors.

Because I have a large number of counties, running the model is very slow using lm(). More frustrating given the number of models I need to produce, lm() produces a much larger object than plm(). This plm() command yields the same coefficients and levels of significance for my main variables.

`plm <- plm(data = mydata, formula = y ~ x + year + state:year, index = "county", model = "within"`

However, these produce substantially different R-squared, Adj. R-squared, etc. I thought I could solve the R-squared problem by calculating the R-squared for `plm` by hand:

`SST <- sum((mydata$y - mean(mydata$y))^2)`

`fit <- (mydata$y - plm$residuals)`

`SSR <- sum((fit - mean(mydata$y))^2)`

`R2 <- SSR / SST`

I tested the R-squared code with `lm` and got the same result reported by `summary(lm)`. However, when I calculated R-squared for `plm` I got a different R-squared (and it was greater than 1).

At this point I checked what the coefficients for my fixed effects in `plm` were and they were different than the coefficients in `lm`.

Can someone please 1) help me understand why I'm getting these differing results and 2) suggest the most efficient way to construct the models I need *and* obtain correct R-squareds? Thanks!